# Remind users who has not added an item in the last 24hrs?

Tags: workflow

To start with: no custom code, only SPD is allowed.

I have a requirement where users has to log in to a site each day and "sign in". List has some columns: Person, State, Country, Date. Can I somehow have a workflow send email to everyone who has not signed in in the last 24hrs? I doubt this is doable but throwing out the question just in case.

Thanks in advance.